# How to solve pen assignment problem?

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

Given:

- A set of $N$ pens with different colors.
- A set of $N$ slots to place the pens. (Which is also is an $k$ by $l$ matrix, for example $80$ pens with $8 \times 10$ matrix of slots)
- A function $diff(A, B)$ that measures the color difference between two pens $A$ and $B$.

Find an assignment of pens to slots that minimizes the total color difference between adjacent pens in the final arrangement.

To be more specific about the problem I'm trying to solve, I'm using $R, G, B$ space to encode colors, and Euclidean distance to find color difference.

I've tried to match this problem to [Assignment Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_problem), in linear assignment problem, the costs are fixed. But in this problem, costs vary depending on adjacent assignments. I also tried to convert problem to other known OR problems like Knapsack problem, TSP etc. but couldn't succeed.

I'm having trouble finding how to solve this problem. How can it be solved?

Comment: This looks like a perfect candidate for a genetic algorithm to me :-)

Comment: @Dominique I also think that G.A. would help a lot. Do you have suggestion for a python library? Also I'm not sure how to implement pen combinations to genes. In the end I'll write code from scratch I think...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One plausible approach is to use integer linear programming.  In particular, let $x_{i,j}=1$ if the $i$th pen is placed into the $j$th slot, or $0$ if not.  Then you can encode your problem as an ILP problem over these variables.  In particular, we have the following constraints:

- Each pen is placed in one slot: $\sum_j x_{i,j}=1$ for each $i$
- Each slot receives one pen: $\sum_i x_{i,j}=1$ for each $j$
- $0 \le x_{i,j} \le 1$ for each $i,j$

For each adjacent pair of slots $j,j'$, let $y_{j,j'}$ be the color difference between the pens placed in slots $j,j'$ have color difference $d$ (or a lower bound on it, at least).  Then we have the following constraints:

- $\text{diff}(i,i') \times (x_{i,j} + x_{i',j'} - 1) \le y_{j,j'}$ for each pair of pens $i,i'$ and each pair of adjacent slots $j,j'$
- $y_{j,j'} \ge 0$ for each pair of adjacent slots $j,j'$

Each of these constraints are linear inequalities in the variables $x_{\cdot},y_{\cdot}$.  Also, the objective function is a linear function of these variables, namely, $\sum_{j,j'} y_{j,j'}$.  Therefore, you can use an off-the-shelf ILP solver to minimize this objective function, subject to all of the inequalities listed above.

The problem instance might be too hard for off-the-shelf ILP solvers to solve.  It will be a huge ILP instance: $\sim N^2$ variables, $\sim 4N^3$ inequalities.  But many ILP solvers have an option to show you the best solution they've found so far, after a certain amount of time elapses, and that might be one way to search for a reasonable (even if not optimal) solution.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is, $y_{j,j'}$ is not fixed, and changes by the pens in slot. Do you suggest me to calculate each $y_{j,j'}$ for pens $i, i'$ in advance?

Comment: @armamut, $y_{j,j'}$ is an integer variable.  Integer linear programming works by listing some variables, and then specifying inequalities on those variables, and letting the ILP solver figure out the best assignment to those variables.  You don't need to calculate the value of $y_{j,j'}$, you just need to provide the inequalities listed above, and the ILP solver will search for the value of $y_{j,j'}$.

Comment: Thank you, I'll read more on the topic and tools.